# How to pass a value into a directives controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller, directive

My directive has a controller and I am trying to figure out how to pass a value from the directive that was passed in.  In the example below 'name' is not valid posted to the console but it shows in the html when rendered.  Obviously my example is an over simplication, but you get the point.

```js
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('helpLabel', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name: '@',
            },
            template: '<span>{{name}}</span>',
            controller: function ($scope) {                
                console.log(name);
            } 
        };
    });
```

```html
<helpLabel name="test"></helpLabel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found is to use bindToController along with controllerAs now effective angular 1.4.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('helpLabel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{},
        bindToConroller: {
            name: '@',
        },
        template: '<span>{{cntrl.name}}</span>',
        controller: function () {                
            console.log(cntrl.name);
        },
        controllerAs: "cntrl"
    };
});
```

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because when it is being rendered to the html, you encapsulated name within {{}}. If you wan't to access the name property within your directive you have to change your code.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('helpLabel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
        },
        template: '<span>{{name}}</span>',
        controller: function ($scope) {                
            console.log($scope.name);
        } 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `console.log(name);`, the variable `name` is not known your directive and hence not able to access it, but since angular has done binding to `'name'` variable, it can render `{{name}}`.

You should access variable `name` as `$scope.name` as variable `name` is present inside current scope.

Modify your code as follow:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('helpLabel', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name: '@',
            },
            template: '<span>{{name}}</span>',
            controller: function ($scope) {                
                console.log($scope.name);
            } 
        };
    });
```